# Swedish character encoding when reading file

Tags: r, character-encoding, data.table

In R, I am trying to read a data file containing Swedish characters. In the following example, the 7th column is "år" (year). Is there a way to correctly read the file so `\u0081r` becomes `ar`?

```r
destfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")                                                 

destfile <- curl::curl_download("https://filebin.ca/3LmXCrAhWp7z/myfile.txt", destfile)

df <- data.table::fread(destfile, encoding = "Latin-1", dec = ",", sep = "\t")[, 1:7] 

head(df)                                                                               
#>                    Namn  X_RAK  Y_RAK X_SMHI Y_SMHI Typ \u0081r
#> 1: Get\u008cb\u008acken 650505 152843      0      0   0    2005
#> 2: Get\u008cb\u008acken 650505 152843      0      0   0    2005
#> 3: Get\u008cb\u008acken 650505 152843      0      0   0    2005
#> 4: Get\u008cb\u008acken 650505 152843      0      0   0    2005
#> 5: Get\u008cb\u008acken 650505 152843      0      0   0    2005
#> 6: Get\u008cb\u008acken 650505 152843      0      0   0    2005
```

Comment: Can you just correct it afterwards? `colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="\u0081r"]<-"ar"`

Comment: I could, but I am looking for a more generic solution since I have real data that contains much more problematic columns.

Comment: Instead of using `fread` could you use `read.table` and select `check.names = FALSE`?

Comment: `read.table` gives me an error: `Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals,  : invalid multibyte string at '<81>r'`

Comment: I tried using `readr::read_delim(..., locale = locale("sv"))` without success as well. I suspect the solution will be importing the data the way you already have, and then finding a utility that replaces characters in the column names programmatically.

Comment: The file is saved using `x-mac-icelandic` encoding if downloaded from `"https://filebin.ca/3LmXCrAhWp7z/myfile.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

The file is saved using `x-mac-icelandic` encoding if downloaded from `"https://filebin.ca/3LmXCrAhWp7z/myfile.txt"`. IMHO the best choice would be copying downloaded file using UTF-8 encoding (see the python code below).

Unfortunately, `curl` keeps throwing `HTTP error 503` so I have downloaded the file manually (and hardcoded the filename in the following code snippet:

```
destfile <- "D:\\Downloads\\myfile.txt"
dUTFfile <- "D:\\Downloads\\myfileUtf8.txt"

pythoncode <- sprintf("python -c \"open( \'%s\', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(open( \'%s\', 'r', encoding='mac_iceland').read())\"", dUTFfile, destfile)
x <- system(pythoncode)

if (x==0) {
    library(data.table, quietly = TRUE)
    df <- data.table::fread(dUTFfile, encoding = "UTF-8", dec = ",", sep = "\t")[, 1:7] 
    print(df)
}
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> 2>NUL del "D:\Downloads\myfileUtf8.txt"

d:\bat> r -q --no-save
> source('D:\\bat\\SO\\43923048.r')

                     Namn  X_RAK  Y_RAK X_SMHI Y_SMHI Typ   Ar
   1:          Getabäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   2:          Getabäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   3:          Getabäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   4:          Getabäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   5:          Getabäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
  ---
1383: Blabergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1384: Blabergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1385: Blabergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1386: Blabergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1387: Blabergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
```

The `pythoncode` string is equivalent to the following `.py` script:

```
outfile = "D:\\Downloads\\myfileUtf8.txt"
inpfile = "D:\\Downloads\\myfile.txt"

with open( outfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fo:
    with open( inpfile, 'r', encoding='mac_iceland') as fi:
      fo.write(fi.read())
```

**Edit** for the sake of completeness: in my system locale, some characters e.g. *Letter A With Ring Above* `å` or `Å`  are *latinized* as `a` and `A`, respectively. Fixed as follows:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Swedish")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252"

> source('D:\\bat\\SO\\43923048.r')
                     Namn  X_RAK  Y_RAK X_SMHI Y_SMHI Typ   År
   1:          Getåbäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   2:          Getåbäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   3:          Getåbäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   4:          Getåbäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
   5:          Getåbäcken 650505 152843      0      0   0 2005
  ---                                                         
1383: Blåbergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1384: Blåbergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1385: Blåbergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1386: Blåbergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
1387: Blåbergsjön BF,myn. 709620 164750      0      0   0 2009
>
```